# gnuplot graph misplaced on canvas

Tags: output, gnuplot, figure

I need to have a graph in a specific format. I am using Gnuplot and try to use the size and terminal size to change the size of my output. However, Gnuplot does some really weird stuff and I don't know how to change things...
I am using Gnuplot Version 4.4 Patchlevel 3.

Here is a minimal example:

```
reset
set size 1
set terminal postscript enhanced color solid linewidth 1 size 15cm,10.5cm font "Helvetica" 16 
set output "C:/..."

set encoding iso_8859_1 #for special characters
set xrange [2.05:3.13] #2. Achse
set yrange [1.5:2.1]
set border 3
set key spacing 1.5
set pointsize 0.6
plot '[...].dat' using 1:2 notitle with points pt 7 lc rgb "#000000" pointsize 1
```

that gets me the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z78gF.jpg 
The graph is halved in size and starts in the middle of the canvas. I cannot change the position by using margins... I thought it might be a problem of size so I set set size 2 which then gave me https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov5Ha.jpg . The graph still starts in the middle left and extends way over the boundaries, while most of the canvas stays white...

I have no idea what's going on and tried all kinds of stuff, but still, the picture won't start in the bottom left corner but somewhere in the middle, being shrinked in size... Somebody had the same problem?

I just want to get a Gnuplot figure of the size 15 cm x 10.5 cm - it can't be that difficult, can it be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can reproduce this with gsview, and I think it's only a matter of viewer configuration. GSview doesn't fit to the bounding box, but uses the size given in the menu "Media". Go to the menu entry `Options` and check `Show Bounding Box`. You should get the correct bounding box shown as dashed box (at least I do).

Comment: Ah this helped a little bit. I was able to set my own format using user defined. The bounding box does, however not fit together with my graph: [link](http://i.imgur.com/bhwWkjo.png?1) It is, as if gsview's view is shifted in respect to the file...

Comment: What do you want the figure for? I'm pretty sure you really want ''encapsulated'' postscript. Just give the terminal option and save as ".eps". Gnuplot itself cannot control the paper size of a plain postscript output. The actual size of your plot itself surely is as you specified it. With eps, most viewers, LaTeX, etc. will cut the plot to the bounding box correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After some messing aroung with gsview and gnuplot I found a solution that works for me that includes basically 4 steps:

1) use eps or even postscript, it doesn't really matter. Do not use the set size command. I used eps and it looks very good, here is one proposition:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color solid linewidth 1 size 15cm,10.5cm font "Helvetica" 22
```

leave the ret as it was and go to

2) GSView: First check "Options - Show Bounding Box". 
Use the commands under "Orientation" to orient canvas and figure so they match each other. This is usually landscape!
Now enter "Media - User Defined" to create a canvas that fits your needs. My figure is 15 by 10.5 cm and my canvas needed to be something like 17 by 12.5 cm.

3) Use b, t, l and r margins to move your figure on the canvas.

4) convert to pdf and take a look at the pdf if it matches your expectations.

I hope this is helpful for some people! It's probably quite a workaround but doesn't take so much time. Maybe it's not very helpful for automatisation...

Comment: So you really want to have a pdf? I recommend updating your very, very old gnuplot version, and to use the pdfcairo terminal. But even your antique version should have the old "pdf" terminal. Surely the windows binary from sf.net has it. Go use that if you cannot update.